# how to use jQuery File Upload plugin to upload files for different categories

Tags: php, jquery, session, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery File Upload plugin to upload images per categories for each of my users. Each user may upload different images for different categories that they are enabled for. However, jQuery File Upload plugin creates a session that shows the same images for all categories. For example if I upload 5 images under Clothes category, when I go to Shoes categories the same images are displayed there when actually I've not uploaded any images there. Is there a way to separate the uploads for each categories? I've checked the jQuery File Upload wiki but there's nothing there to help in this regard.

FYI: I'm using PHP for server side.

Comment: I had to drop the plugin and use Dropzone instead. Everything is  fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the reason I was blocked from asking further questions. I have found the solution. However I had to drop the plugin and used Dropzone instead. Everything is working fine now.